experiment with BTRFS RAID 1 (mirror) and recovery after disk failure
I am just trying learn more about Btrfs. I am using it years on sigle harddrives, sometimes for backups (rsync on external drive and then snapshot), it works fine. But I had some bad experience with USB disk when whole filesystem failed after problem with USB connection (bad cable), i had problems with extremely slow running virtual when disk image was on Btrfs and of course i did read some horrible stories about other failures.
So i am trying experiment more before i will use it again. This time i am considering using it for fileserver with two 12TB harddrives in Btrfs mirror, because resync with mdraid is very slow and always must be synced whole drive.
There is no risk of losing my data, this is only test with copy of something.
I am using two USB drives, different types, different USB-SATA converters, but exactly same size/capacity (same number of LBA blocks). I did create Btrfs with this command:
mkfs.btrfs -m raid1 /dev/sde1 /dev/sdf1
Then i used this command, because i think data wasn't redundant. I wasn't totally sure.
btrfs balance start -dconvert=raid1 /mnt/hdd
Now seems to be all in RAID1 and after i did fill filesystem with some files it looks like this:
btrfs filesystem usage /mnt/hdd
Overall:
    Device size:                 931.52GiB
    Device allocated:            698.12GiB
    Device unallocated:          233.40GiB
    Device missing:                  0.00B
    Device slack:                    0.00B
    Used:                        673.84GiB
    Free (estimated):            128.12GiB      (min: 128.12GiB)
    Free (statfs, df):           128.04GiB
    Data ratio:                       2.00
    Metadata ratio:                   2.00
    Global reserve:              346.00MiB      (used: 0.00B)
    Multiple profiles:                  no

Data,RAID1: Size:348.00GiB, Used:336.58GiB (96.72%)
   /dev/sde1     348.00GiB
   /dev/sdg1     348.00GiB

Metadata,RAID1: Size:1.00GiB, Used:347.16MiB (33.90%)
   /dev/sde1       1.00GiB
   /dev/sdg1       1.00GiB

System,RAID1: Size:64.00MiB, Used:80.00KiB (0.12%)
   /dev/sde1      64.00MiB
   /dev/sdg1      64.00MiB

Unallocated:
   /dev/sde1     116.70GiB
   /dev/sdg1     116.70GiB

After that i did try disconnect one of drives two times and once i did power it off. Linux did write some errors in log, but filesystem stayed available and working all the time.
[2198337.107814] btrfs_dev_stat_inc_and_print: 48 callbacks suppressed
[2198337.107822] BTRFS error (device sde1): bdev /dev/sdf1 errs: wr 63, rd 0, flush 0, corrupt 0, gen 0
[2198337.107843] BTRFS error (device sde1): bdev /dev/sdf1 errs: wr 64, rd 0, flush 0, corrupt 0, gen 0
[2198337.114935] BTRFS error (device sde1): bdev /dev/sdf1 errs: wr 65, rd 0, flush 0, corrupt 0, gen 0
[2198337.114941] BTRFS error (device sde1): bdev /dev/sdf1 errs: wr 66, rd 0, flush 0, corrupt 0, gen 0
[2198337.114944] BTRFS error (device sde1): bdev /dev/sdf1 errs: wr 67, rd 0, flush 0, corrupt 0, gen 0
[2198337.114946] BTRFS error (device sde1): bdev /dev/sdf1 errs: wr 68, rd 0, flush 0, corrupt 0, gen 0
[2198337.114948] BTRFS error (device sde1): bdev /dev/sdf1 errs: wr 69, rd 0, flush 0, corrupt 0, gen 0
[2198337.114950] BTRFS error (device sde1): bdev /dev/sdf1 errs: wr 70, rd 0, flush 0, corrupt 0, gen 0
[2198337.114951] BTRFS error (device sde1): bdev /dev/sdf1 errs: wr 71, rd 0, flush 0, corrupt 0, gen 0
[2198337.114953] BTRFS error (device sde1): bdev /dev/sdf1 errs: wr 72, rd 0, flush 0, corrupt 0, gen 0
[2198340.923129] BTRFS warning (device sde1): lost page write due to IO error on /dev/sdf1 (-5)
[2198340.923148] BTRFS warning (device sde1): lost page write due to IO error on /dev/sdf1 (-5)
[2198340.923162] BTRFS warning (device sde1): lost page write due to IO error on /dev/sdf1 (-5)
[2198340.923332] BTRFS error (device sde1): error writing primary super block to device 2
[2198341.025299] BTRFS info (device sde1): last unmount of filesystem 95590c2d-1105-4f5a-8438-bca59a8dc0a1
[2198341.064805] BTRFS warning (device sde1): lost page write due to IO error on /dev/sdf1 (-5)
[2198341.064821] BTRFS warning (device sde1): lost page write due to IO error on /dev/sdf1 (-5)
[2198341.064832] BTRFS warning (device sde1): lost page write due to IO error on /dev/sdf1 (-5)

Then i tried umount filesystem, mount it again, then check filesystem for errors etc...
For first glance, everything seems to be fine. Filesystem can be mounted and used without any problems.
In dmesg was more related messages
[2207911.167036] BTRFS error (device sde1): bad tree block start, mirror 1 want 747718950912 have 1012965885011713927
[2207911.203235] BTRFS info (device sde1): read error corrected: ino 0 off 747718950912 (dev /dev/sdg1 sector 525017824)
[2207911.203767] BTRFS info (device sde1): read error corrected: ino 0 off 747718955008 (dev /dev/sdg1 sector 525017832)
[2207911.204253] BTRFS info (device sde1): read error corrected: ino 0 off 747718959104 (dev /dev/sdg1 sector 525017840)
[2207911.205288] BTRFS info (device sde1): read error corrected: ino 0 off 747718963200 (dev /dev/sdg1 sector 525017848)

And when i tried btrfsck or btrfs /dev/sde1 check --repair /dev/sde1 it did found some bad checksums.
btrfs check --repair /dev/sde1 
enabling repair mode
WARNING:

        Do not use --repair unless you are advised to do so by a developer
        or an experienced user, and then only after having accepted that no
        fsck can successfully repair all types of filesystem corruption. E.g.
        some software or hardware bugs can fatally damage a volume.
        The operation will start in 10 seconds.
        Use Ctrl-C to stop it.
10 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1
Starting repair.
Opening filesystem to check...
Checking filesystem on /dev/sde1
UUID: 95590c2d-1105-4f5a-8438-bca59a8dc0a1
[1/7] checking root items
Fixed 0 roots.
[2/7] checking extents
checksum verify failed on 747718164480 wanted 0x32e9b6fd found 0x957a811e
checksum verify failed on 747718197248 wanted 0xbfcf3844 found 0xabedda20
checksum verify failed on 747718246400 wanted 0xc887120b found 0xd61ac27b
checksum verify failed on 747718279168 wanted 0xd8baaf62 found 0x47f1a77c
checksum verify failed on 747720146944 wanted 0xbba4079a found 0xd4965e19
checksum verify failed on 747720212480 wanted 0xc70d98ba found 0xbb3c21ba
checksum verify failed on 747720720384 wanted 0x67423c88 found 0xf79b9ab6
checksum verify failed on 747720736768 wanted 0x98a188cc found 0x17e75759
checksum verify failed on 747720753152 wanted 0xad1610ea found 0x676e72e6
checksum verify failed on 747720900608 wanted 0x7650f887 found 0x2618eff9
checksum verify failed on 747720916992 wanted 0x5d79a1b5 found 0x4a9a1aef
checksum verify failed on 747720933376 wanted 0x7fe59aee found 0x2f67941e
checksum verify failed on 747720949760 wanted 0x33626f02 found 0x80ed7f05
checksum verify failed on 747720966144 wanted 0x1b60524d found 0x03458c70

checksum verify failed on 747718967296 wanted 0x41a08182 found 0x8badf76c
checksum verify failed on 747718983680 wanted 0xb004ab0c found 0x24afdd47
checksum verify failed on 747719180288 wanted 0x82533f95 found 0xdee1f5ed
checksum verify failed on 747719196672 wanted 0xa2b99fc6 found 0x51307dbb
checksum verify failed on 747719213056 wanted 0xaa968280 found 0x638fb5c5
checksum verify failed on 747719262208 wanted 0x35fd0f6c found 0xf2ecea36
checksum verify failed on 747719278592 wanted 0x48f80915 found 0x0e6f229a
checksum verify failed on 747719294976 wanted 0x3f85e54f found 0x6ac8a77e
checksum verify failed on 747719344128 wanted 0x68a53c37 found 0xd044ca62
checksum verify failed on 747719360512 wanted 0x7fd9af5e found 0xa72974e5
checksum verify failed on 747719376896 wanted 0x7a0d4269 found 0xe6f78421
checksum verify failed on 747719426048 wanted 0x1cff7672 found 0x537bd5c8
checksum verify failed on 747719442432 wanted 0x1a5b9fd5 found 0x96e141a8
checksum verify failed on 747719507968 wanted 0xaea35bd5 found 0xf469bac7
checksum verify failed on 747719524352 wanted 0x699ba141 found 0xafeab08a
checksum verify failed on 747719557120 wanted 0x16889920 found 0x898a615d
checksum verify failed on 747719589888 wanted 0x44e7e622 found 0x095a11b9
checksum verify failed on 747719622656 wanted 0xc44325c4 found 0xea6faa22
checksum verify failed on 747719639040 wanted 0x90103feb found 0x6ba8a5bd
checksum verify failed on 747720015872 wanted 0xc6afff1d found 0x8d831049
checksum verify failed on 747720065024 wanted 0xe761a3ab found 0x80fc9ba5
checksum verify failed on 747720081408 wanted 0xf668d7b3 found 0xcae4f091
checksum verify failed on 747720097792 wanted 0x112922ad found 0x6cb0b91d
No device size related problem found
[3/7] checking free space tree
[4/7] checking fs roots
[5/7] checking only csums items (without verifying data)
[6/7] checking root refs
[7/7] checking quota groups skipped (not enabled on this FS)
found 361740599296 bytes used, no error found
total csum bytes: 352906768
total tree bytes: 364068864
total fs tree bytes: 1097728
total extent tree bytes: 2097152
btree space waste bytes: 5012912
file data blocks allocated: 367454699520
 referenced 357444206592

Now i am running btrfs scrub start /mnt/hdd and it already runs maybe hour or so.
So - what is the best way how to deal with this kind of situations when one disk failing, or can be disconnected because bad cable, or power fails...
Server will have UPS, but still, one drive can fail anytime, so how much is Btrfs resilient against it? Is it bad idea use Btrfs RAID 1?
With mdraid i did replace hard drives many times, i know what to expect and where it can help and where cannot. But short or non existent resync is very very tempting.
btrfs scrub status /mnt/hdd
UUID:             95590c2d-1105-4f5a-8438-bca59a8dc0a1
Scrub started:    Sun Jun  9 22:17:22 2024
Status:           running
Duration:         15:07:44
Time left:        0:59:35
ETA:              Mon Jun 10 14:24:45 2024
Total to scrub:   673.84GiB
Bytes scrubbed:   632.33GiB  (93.84%)
Rate:             11.89MiB/s
Error summary:    verify=14 csum=3078
  Corrected:      3092
  Uncorrectable:  0
  Unverified:     0

No, hard drives are not that slow (they can write more than 120MB/s), it just does almost nothing, more than 15 hours with minimal IO and minimal CPU load.
Linux version 6.1.90
sys-fs/btrfs-progs-6.7.1
UPDATE:
Btrfs finished scrub and it seems to be repaired and fully working again. But almost 16 hours? It doesn't seem like any benefit against mdraid at all. On my experimental filesystem are only hundrets of files, whole structure is very small and simple in comparison what i intended store on bigger 12T discs.
btrfs scrub status /mnt/hdd
UUID:             95590c2d-1105-4f5a-8438-bca59a8dc0a1
Scrub started:    Sun Jun  9 22:17:22 2024
Status:           finished
Duration:         15:46:09
Total to scrub:   673.84GiB
Rate:             12.15MiB/s
Error summary:    verify=14 csum=53994
  Corrected:      54008
  Uncorrectable:  0
  Unverified:     0

btrfs check --repair /dev/sde1
enabling repair mode
WARNING:

        Do not use --repair unless you are advised to do so by a developer
        or an experienced user, and then only after having accepted that no
        fsck can successfully repair all types of filesystem corruption. E.g.
        some software or hardware bugs can fatally damage a volume.
        The operation will start in 10 seconds.
        Use Ctrl-C to stop it.
10 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1
Starting repair.
Opening filesystem to check...
Checking filesystem on /dev/sde1
UUID: 95590c2d-1105-4f5a-8438-bca59a8dc0a1
[1/7] checking root items
Fixed 0 roots.
[2/7] checking extents
No device size related problem found
[3/7] checking free space tree
[4/7] checking fs roots
[5/7] checking only csums items (without verifying data)
[6/7] checking root refs
[7/7] checking quota groups skipped (not enabled on this FS)
found 361763938304 bytes used, no error found
total csum bytes: 352929528
total tree bytes: 364101632
total fs tree bytes: 1097728
total extent tree bytes: 2097152
btree space waste bytes: 5018449
file data blocks allocated: 367478005760
 referenced 357467512832


You invested a lot of time to write this question. I'm just wondering how you can say something like, "It doesn't seem like any benefit against mdraid at all."? I suggest you try more of BTRFS, you knowledge is still incomplete. As a cliffhanger, BTRFS-RAID has a lot advantages over MDRAID. ;-)

Even on mdraid i still want to use BTRFS, so i still will have COW and CRC's on data and metadata. But i will need much more tests and try more recovery scenarios until i gain some confidence about it.
For example i will need simulate not only shortly disconnected but bad harddrive and try replace it several times. I did try it with small flash drives in past, but with bigger capacity it is little different. It took unexpectedly more time. I know 466GiB (500G) is not that big, but little bit closer to 12TB than 16G flash drive was.
